# How do I get this button to go beside the email field

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I get the subscribe button to go beside the email field of the form.. and the hover doesn't seem to be working on the subscribe button

using bootstrap and HTML5 and CSS

```
<form class="subscribe_form">
<div class="subscrive_group wow fadeInUp">
<input class="form-control subscribe_mail" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address">
<input class="btn-form" type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
subscribe_form {
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
color: #CCCCC6;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
margin-top: 0;
outline: medium none;
width: 75%;
}

.subscribe_form .btn-form {
margin: 10px;
}

.btn-form {
color: #00bfff;
padding: 10px 30px;
font-weight: 500;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 200px;
transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
border: 1px solid #00bfff;
background-color: #fff;
letter-spacing: .5px;
font-size: 16px;   

}

.btn-form:hover,
.btn-form:active {
border: 1px solid #00bfff;
background-color: #fff;
color: #00bfff;}
```

heres what happened when I tried this below (image attached[image])

Here is the rest of the code for that section

```
<section class="works service-page">
<div class="container">
<h2 class="subtitle wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-duration="500ms">TEXT     </h2>
<p class="subtitle-des wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay=".5s" data-wow-duration="500ms">
                   TEXT
</p>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 ">
<figure class="wow fadeInLeft animated portfolio-item" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="0ms">
<figcaption>
<h2>
<a href="#" class="figma">
                                    text</a>  <span class="par-text-one"><a href="#">text</a></span>      

</h2>
<p class="para">
                              text
</p>
</figcaption>
<div class="img-wrapper">
<img src="images/" class="img-responsive" alt="this is a title" >
<div class="overlay">
<div class="buttons">       
<a target="_blank" href="">Discover</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<figcaption>
<p class="para">text
<br>
text
</p>
</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 ">
<figure class="wow fadeInLeft animated portfolio-item" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="0ms">
<figcaption>
<h2>
<a href="#" class="figma">
text </a>  <span class="par-text-one"><a href="#">text </a></span>      

</h2>
<p class="para">text
</p>
</figcaption>
<div class="img-wrapper">
<img src="images/.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="this is a title" >
<div class="overlay">
<div class="buttons">       
<a target="_blank" href="">Discover</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<figcaption>
<p class="para">text
<br>text
</p>
</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 boxed">

<h2> More Products Coming Soon! </h2>
<p class="para-form">
text
</p>
<p class="para-blue">text
</p>
<div class="container">   
<form class="subscribe_form">
<div class="subscrive_group wow fadeInUp row col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input class="form-control subscribe_mail" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input class="btn-form" type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: The button is already next to the field...https://jsfiddle.net/4fn2gtn1/

Comment: It's not in live view

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `form-inline` class on your `<form>` tag.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline.

```
<form class="subscribe_form form-inline">
    <div class="subscrive_group wow fadeInUp">
        <input class="form-control subscribe_mail" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address">
        <input class="btn-form" type="submit" value="Subscribe">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you do that, and then you add more form elements in the future, it's going to break, also, it only works on viewports bigger than 768px

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<form class="subscribe_form">
<div class="subscrive_group wow fadeInUp row col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control subscribe_mail" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="btn-form" type="submit" value="Subscribe">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I just added the rest of the code for that section as well, just in case that helps

Comment: that worked except now the subscribe button it off the box that the form is in,,, I feel like I tried everything to get it in there but it's not going. I don't know what the issue is ... and my button hover and active doesn't seem to be working either :(